# Rails model accept float only between 0 and 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got model where I stored users percentage progress - specifically it is a `percent_progress` field, `float` between `0` (0%) to `1` (100%) in a `JourneyProgress` model. I'm just wondering how to protect this field so that the wrong numbers don't get there?

Here is my migration:

```
create_table :journey_progresses do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :journey, foreign_key: true
  t.float :percent_progress
  t.string :finished_at

  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: `validates :percent_progress, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 1 }` should work

Comment: Ok but this is validation in a model directly. I'm just curious - is it possible to lock such data in a migration?

Comment: You can't do that out of the box. You can look into gems that do that, for example [MV](https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core) or you can write custom sql to set constraints. But they might be different depending on the dbms you're using.

Comment: @mr_muscle note the question's title: _"Rails **model** accept float only between 0 and 1"_. If you want a database constraint instead of (or in addition to) a model validation, you should change it accordingly. (also add the database you're using)

Comment: unrelated, but I wouldn't mane the field "percent_progress" - "percent" makes me expect a value between 1 and 100. `1 percent_progress` doesn't sound like completed. Perhaps call it "progress_portion" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validations for this:

journey_progress.rb

```
validates :percent_progress, inclusion: 0.0..1.0
```

Comment: this will accept only decimal values, if you want to accept both decimal and integer you can do something like this: 
`validates :percent_progress, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 1 }`

Comment: if you want to ciustomize the error message you can do this: `validates :percent_progress, inclusion: { in: 0.0..1.0, message: "must be between 0 and 1" }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish that you need to install this gem [mv-postgresql](https://rubygems.org/gems/mv-postgresql).

#### Usage

```rb
create_table :journey_progresses do |t|
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :journey, foreign_key: true
  t.float :percent_progress, inclusion: 0.0..1.0
  t.string :finished_at

  t.timestamps
end
```

Next go to your `model` and add this line

```rb
class JourneyProgress ActiveRecord::Base
  enforce_migration_validations
end
```

Comment: He did not say that he's using postgres.